# How to save an animated GIF to a variable using Pillow

Tags: variables, save, gif, python-imaging-library

I found out from [here](http://pythoninformer.com/python-libraries/pillow/creating-animated-gif/) that I can create and save animated GIFs using Pillow. However, it doesn't look like [the `save` method](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/reference/Image.html) returns any value.

I can save the GIF to a file and then open that file using `Image.open`, but that seems unnecessary, given that I don't really want the GIF to be saved.

How can I save the GIF to a variable, rather than a file?
That is, I would like to be able to do `some_variable.show()` and display a GIF, without ever having to save the GIF onto my computer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To avoid writing any files, you can just save your image to `BytesIO` object. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import division
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from io import BytesIO

N = 25          # number of frames

# Create individual frames
frames = []
for n in range(N):
    frame = Image.new("RGB", (200, 150), (25, 25, 255*(N-n)//N))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(frame)
    x, y = frame.size[0]*n/N, frame.size[1]*n/N
    draw.ellipse((x, y, x+40, y+40), 'yellow')
    # Saving/opening is needed for better compression and quality
    fobj = BytesIO()
    frame.save(fobj, 'GIF')
    frame = Image.open(fobj)
    frames.append(frame)

# Save the frames as animated GIF to BytesIO
animated_gif = BytesIO()
frames[0].save(animated_gif,
               format='GIF',
               save_all=True,
               append_images=frames[1:],      # Pillow >= 3.4.0
               delay=0.1,
               loop=0)
animated_gif.seek(0,2)
print ('GIF image size = ', animated_gif.tell())

# Optional: display image
#animated_gif.seek(0)
#ani = Image.open(animated_gif)
#ani.show()

# Optional: write contents to file
animated_gif.seek(0)
open('animated.gif', 'wb').write(animated_gif.read())
```

In the end, variable `animated_gif` contains contents of the following image:

[image: Sunset]

However, displaying an animated GIF in Python is not very reliable. `ani.show()` from the code above displays only first frame on my machine.

Comment: You still are saving it and then reloading it into the variable `animated_gif`. How can I get `animated_gif` to be the animation without needing to have that `frames[0].save` line?

Comment: @ProQ, this is the way. It might look suboptimal or strange, but this is just how PIL/Pillow is written. Moreover, your question was: "How can I save the GIF to a variable, rather than a file?" - And this is the answer.

Comment: Moreover, each frame also has to be saved/loaded to improve quality and size of the resulting animation. That's just how PIL works right now (tested with Pillow 5.1.0).